# How do I cut a popsicle stick lengthwise?

Tags: cutting, wood

Need to do this for my art project. I tried using a normal wire cutter but the wood just doesnt break

Comment: http://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/284/24

Comment: @CreationEdge How is this not a duplicate? both the answers are the same even if the question is worded _slightly_ differently

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I cut popsicle craft sticks without splitting them?](http://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-can-i-cut-popsicle-craft-sticks-without-splitting-them)

Comment: @Matt Well, this is asking to split them and mine is asking how to cut them without splitting them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is limited by not having an indication of the resources available to you. One of the better tools would be a scroll saw, often called a jig saw. The tabletop versions are well suited to light duty cuts such as popsicle sticks.

Another suitable tool, somewhat unwieldy, is the rotary hobby tool, often called a dremel tool, from the brand name frequently associated with this type of item. There are various bits available for this device, but it would be challenging to handle safely for such small pieces.

Only recently, there appears on the 'net a number of videos showing people using either a rotary tool such as the dremel, or a hand drill and even a right-angle disc grinder. The latter is seriously overpowered for this application, but the key feature is that the cutting "bit" is a circle of paper.

Multiple circles of the same diameter are cut, glued together using ordinary adhesive and attached to the rotary device. The faster the speed one can manage, the better the results. Even wood as thick as 25 mm (1 inch) is shown being cut with a paper disc!

I used The YouTube, searched for "cutting with paper" and found a number of returns. One of them shows the rotary tool at the very start. I did not view the entire video, having seen others representative of this method.

[Cutting with paper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJU75uXOIBE)

EDIT: An additional method of attacking the sticks would be to use a box knife or similar sharp instrument. Place a solid straight edge on the stick and score repeatedly along the edge. Use as much force as necessary to cut into the surface, but not so much as to crack the stick along grain lines.

If you can ensure exact positioning, consider to score one side then the other before attempting to split the stick in two. It may be necessary to alternate sides when scoring in order to slice completely through the stick.

Comment: I think the simplest (safest) option is @fred_dot_u's knife and straight-edge. I would use an X-acto knife and and make multiple passes until you have cut through the stick.  The thing to be careful about is that your straight edge could slip and cause you to cut yourself.  I suggest taping the popsicle stick down to the working surface to keep it stable, and then (a trick from working with polymer clay), use a stack or two of playing cards at the same height as your popsicle stick, to support and stabilize the width of the straight edge, which is likely wider than your popsicle stick.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get my hand on a jig saw. Work wonders!

Answer (score 3):

Use a razor knife and a straight edge.

1. Mount the straight edge to your popsicle stick so that it creates a hard edge right down the center. You can simply tape it to a metal ruler.
2. Now set the razor knife on the stick and pull it lengthwise down the stick, maintaining a straight line, by keeping it tight to the ruler. You don't need to press hard. Just push it down enough to score the surface.
3. Go back over the scored line a few times, lightly pressing the razor knife (scalpel, exacto knife). Eventually it will work it's way through the wood in a very straight, smooth, and controlled manner.